# close zelect dropdown on click of a sibling

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have following html code ( Rails erb view )-

```
<%= select_tag :destination, options_for_select(@destinations, params["destination"]), :id => 'destination', :style => 'width:100%;' %>
<div class='dropdown-icon destination-icon'>
 <i class='fa fa-chevron-down'></i>
</div>
```

& following js code -

```
  $(document).click(function(){
    $('.zelect').removeClass("open");
    $('.zelect .dropdown').hide();
  })

  $('.zelect').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  })

  $('.dropdown-icon.destination-icon').click(function(e){
    var zelect = $(this).siblings(".zelect");
    if( zelect.hasClass("open") ){
      zelect.removeClass("open");
      zelect.children(".dropdown").hide();
    }
    else{
      zelect.addClass("open");
      zelect.children(".dropdown").show();            
    }    
  });
```

What I want to do is close zelect dropdown on clicking anywhere except for zelect input & destination-icon.

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do smth. like this:

```
$(documetn).ready(function() {
  $(document).click(function(event) {
      if (!$(event.target).closest('.zelect').length) {
        $('.zelect').removeClass('open');
      }
    });
})
```

Just adjust it to your situation.